# How to replace a RMI server for another RMI server using the same connection?

Tags: java, rmi

I'm working on a project where I have n clients connected to a RMI Server(Primary RMI Server). This server has another server connected to it, called the Backup RMI Server. The backup server is supposed to assume the role of the Primary RMI Server when it fails/is shutdown(e.g. a CTRL+C), becoming the Primary RMI Server.

In order to preserve the connection between the clients and the server without having to connect everything again or make the client lookup (**Naming.lookup**) for the server again is there a way to transfer the connection between the first server to the other?

I've already tried using **LocateRegistry.getRegistry(PORT)** on the backup server, at the same port used in **LocateRegistry.createRegistry(PORT).rebind(RMINAME,this)** when creating the "RMI connection" (I know it's not a *connection* like a socket, but it's just to keep things simple). Didn't work out, or at least I wasn't sure it was beeing used properly.

**RMI Server class**

```
try {
// First try to connect to Primary server (the case where this is 
//supposed to be Backup server)
    ci = (RMIInterface) Naming.lookup("RMIConnection");
// This function is what makes the Backup server aware that the Primary
// server failed. It's a while(true) loop with a Thread.sleep(2000)
// that invokes a simple RMI method to test the connection
   checkPrimaryServerStatus();
} 
catch (java.rmi.ConnectException e) {
       System.out.println("No primary RMIServer yet. Connecting...");
} finally {
     // If it isn't backup server, creates connection
         if (!isBackup) {
             try {
              LocateRegistry.createRegistry(RMIPORT).rebind(RMINAME, this);
             } catch (Exception err) {
                 System.out.println("\nERROR: Something went wrong. Aborting program...");
                 err.printStackTrace();
                 System.exit(-1);
             }
        }
}
```

**RMI Client class**

```
try {
    ci = (RMIInterface) Naming.lookup("RMIConnection");
} catch (java.rmi.ConnectException e) {
    System.out.println("\nConnect the server first.");
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

This creates the primary and backup servers properly, however if the primary is shutdown and the backup takes over, the users can't communicate with the backup as they could with the primary.
The problem is "transfering" the connection from one to another.

Comment: There is no such thing as an RMI connection, and there is therefore no such thing as losing it or transferring it. There is merely possession of a stub. If that stub ceases working, or the remote object it came from is unexported, the caller will get a `RemoteException` of some kind. At that point it should reacquire the stub, which means a new `Naming.lookup()` in your scenario. which will point it to a different server if you've rebound that name to point to it, or replaced that Registry entirely with a new one with new bindings.

Comment: I am confused. In the new server(former backup server), to aquire the stub that the former primary server created, how can I do that? If I do a lookup won't the server become a client?

Comment: It is the *clients* that have to reacquire the stub.